# clang 3.4 C++14 support

Tags: c++, c++14, clang++

I am using [travis.ci](https://travis-ci.org/) to do automated test builds of my git repositories.

For linux they use: Ubuntu 12.04
With clang 3.4

According to the [clang page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) all C++ 14 language features are supported by Clang 3.4 (as long as you use the -std=c++1y flag).

So far so good:
I also need to use `std::index_sequence<t0,...,tn>` which is library feature [N3658](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3658.html) not a language feature. But I can not find any specific documentation on updating the C++ standard library for clang to make sure this feature is supported (it is not supported out of the box).

TestCode:

```
#include <utility>
int main() {
    std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>    seq;
}
```

TestBuild:

```
> clang++ -std=c++1y pl.cpp
pl.cpp:3:10: error: no member named 'index_sequence' in namespace 'std'
    std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>    seq;
    ~~~~~^
pl.cpp:3:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'seq'
    std::index_sequence<1,2,3,4>    seq;
                                    ^
2 errors generated.
```

## Update:

Based on the suggestion below I tried to use libc++.
Pretty sure I did something wrong but I have never tried to use an alternative standard library so am not sure what is going wrong here. Will digg in tonight. But if you have a suggestion then please leave a comment.

```
> sudo apt-get install -qq libc++1 libc6 libc++-dev

> clang++ -stdlib=libc++ pl.cpp
pl.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found
#include <utility>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What if you use libc++ instead of libstdc++? `-stdlib=libc++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the answer seems to be to install g++-4.9
This will update the standard libraries already installed to a point where clang will be able to compile the code.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

## Because I also use llvm-cov from my makefile
## I have to make sure it is in the path.
a=$(sudo find / -name llvm-cov | head -1)
sudo ln -s ${a} /usr/bin/llvm-cov
```

So this is what I added to `travis.yml` file

```
before_install:
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo apt-get update;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then sudo apt-get install g++-4.9;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then a=$(sudo find / -name llvm-cov | head -1);sudo ln -s ${a} /usr/bin/llvm-cov;fi
```

After I consolidate my g++ and clang++ pre-build code:

```
before_install:
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux"];                         then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux"];                         then sudo apt-get update;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux"];                         then sudo apt-get install -qq g++-4.9;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "g++" ];     then sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc  gcc  /usr/bin/gcc-4.9  90;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "g++" ];     then sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++  g++  /usr/bin/g++-4.9  90;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "g++" ];     then sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-4.9 90;fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" -a "$CXX" == "clang++" ]; then a=$(sudo find / -name llvm-cov | head -1);sudo ln -s ${a} /usr/bin/llvm-cov;fi
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html, libstdc++ supports this at least given the most recent version. Ubuntu 12.04 contains [GCC 4.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all), where this is obviously not supported. `precise-backports` does not contain a newer version of libstdc++.

However, via https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test, newer versions of GCC and with it, libstdc++, can be obtained. I don't know whether Travis supports installing from other repositories, or not, though.

Comment: CLang is **not** gcc.

Comment: @Serge but Clang most definitely can and will use libstdc++ if not instructed otherwise..

Comment: @SergeBallesta clang uses GNU libstdc++ and headers by default. Clearly this is not a compiler issue, but a standard library one.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo : That's true. My remark was just that the answer could be more explicit on that.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. Thanks for the hint.